Grant permissions from the command line
I want to grant a permission to an application (Cliclick, needs permission to control the computer), but currently only have ssh access to the machine I'd like to do this on.  Is there any way to grant permission via the command line?  I'm coming from Linux so it seems crazy that there would be settings that can only be controlled via GUI.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Make sure you have a backup and remote access to this mac before you try changing the TCC database remotely. Or line up someone to do a restore in person.

Reason enough to stick with Linux!

You may be able to have some luck with security(1) or editing the per-user TCC.db or this tool https://github.com/brysontyrrell/tccprofile. However keep in mind Apple purposefully made granting permissions programmically hard as a security measure. They even forbid using accessibility api to click the grant permission button.

This is by design. You’ll want to set up a ssh tunnel and remote in using VNC as the expedient way to manage the TCC database via GUI tools.
I’m not skilled enough to wrangle these sort of settings via ssh, but perhaps someone else will chime in with an edit or a better answer explaining how to accomplish what you seek without an MDM enrollment to push this from a remote management server rather than ssh
The way many do this at scale at work is by using an MDM push.

How are you supposed to set up a piece of software (VNC or otherwise) to control the computer, when the original problem is that permission to control the computer can't be granted through CLI?

You can enable remote access entirely from ssh. You can’t manage the trust database. They are separate operations with separate requirements @Dev VNC server is built into the OS
